# Add multidimensional array in multidimensional array at specific position

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that is built like this (don't mind the string lengths, I modified the values)

```
array(27) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Arsenal FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Liverpool FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "2"
  }
[2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Manchester United"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "3"
  }
}
```

Now I want to add an array, that is built like this

```
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(18) "Chelsea FC"
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "4"
```

between the second and third array element.

I have done it like this

```
$this->clubs = array_slice($this->clubs, 0, 2, true) +
['name' => 'Chelsea FC', 'id' => 4] +
array_slice($this->clubs, 2, sizeof($this->clubs), true);
```

However, this returns the following array

```
array(27) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Arsenal FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Liverpool FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "2"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(20) "Chelsea FC"
  ["id"]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Manchester United"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "3"
  }
```

As you can see, the array is added to the correct position, but not in the correct format (not multidimensional). What I would need to do now, is to add the array at the position and increase the count of all other indexes.

I tried to achieve it like this

```
if ($otherClubs->count() > 0) {

    array_walk($this->clubs, function($item, $key) use($index, $otherClubs) {
        if ($key > $index) {
            $this->clubs[$key + $otherClubs->count()] = $item;
            unset($this->otherClubs[$key]);
        }
    });
}
```

but this destroyed the array completely

```
array(36) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Arsenal FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Liverpool FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "2"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(20) "Chelsea FC"
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "4"
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** try **array_splice**:The OPTION 1 is better and less messy and it will preserve the key.

**1):**

```
$arr=array (
    '0'=>
    array(
        "name"=>"Arsenal FC",
        "id"=>"1"
    ),
    '1'=>
    array(
        "name"=>"Liverpool FC",
        "id"=>"2"
    ),
    '2'=>
    array(
        "name"=>"Manchester United",
        "id"=>"3"
));

array_splice($arr, 2, 0, array(array('name' => 'Chelsea FC', 'id' => 4)));
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
```

> **OUTPUT:**

`array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Arsenal FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Liverpool FC"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Chelsea FC"
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "Manchester United"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}`

**OR** your style of attempt.

**2):**

```
<?php 
$arr=array (
    '0'=>
    array(
        "name"=>"Arsenal FC",
        "id"=>"1"
    ),
    '1'=>
    array(
        "name"=>"Liverpool FC",
        "id"=>"2"
    ),
    '2'=>
    array(
        "name"=>"Manchester United",
        "id"=>"3"
));


$arr = array_values(array_slice($arr, 0, 2, true) + array(sizeof($arr)=>array('name' => 'Chelsea FC', 'id' => 4)) + array_slice($arr, 2, sizeof($arr), true));
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Your first attempt is much better than the one I used. And it works without problems! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `+` tries the merge the array. So the array you are trying to add should also be multidimensional

```
$this->clubs = array_slice($this->clubs, 0, 2, true) +
[1 => ['name' => 'Chelsea FC', 'id' => 4]] +
array_slice($this->clubs, 2, sizeof($this->clubs), true);
```

The downside is that you should provide a key to the array that you want to add.

Or you could use `array_merge`

```
$this->clubs = array_merge(
    array_slice($this->clubs, 0, 2, true),
    [['name' => 'Chelsea FC', 'id' => 4]],
    array_slice($this->clubs, 2, sizeof($this->clubs), true)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but when I do it like in your comment, the new array element is nowhere to be found in the new array, meaning when I dump it, it's simply not there

Comment: The new array must have a key to have a successful merge

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wrote, that I would need to increase all the other array values, so the new array element doesn't override the old ones. See my attempt with `array_walk`. But the problem I would have there, is, that I would increase the 4th element to have the index `5` and override the 5th array element. I need to somehow increase all the values without overriding others

Comment: Or just use `array_merge` if you don't want to provide a key (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: array_merge however does not preserve keys, and I can't simply invent a new one. However, this lead me to another solution. I simply added a key, generated by the md5 hash value of the name and the id (so it's unique)

`[md5($club->name . $club->id) => ['name' => ' - ' . $club->name, 'id' => $club->id]] +`

This seems to work.

Comment: So for some you want the preserve (the first 2) and others  you want to increase (3 and 4)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94694/discussion-between-stijn-janssen-and-musterknabe).